# Linker error when I deploy into device

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, afoauth2manager

I use Pods to install the AFOAuth2Manager library and here is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.2'
pod 'AFOAuth2Manager'
```

I open the project in xcworkspace file and I can build it in the simulator. But when I try to build it to my iPhone 6S, it failed and here is the error log:

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I edit other linker flags in build setting.I found the -l"AFNetwork" is inside $(inherited) so I deleted $(inherited) and add -l"AFOAuth2Manager" then the error message change to ld: library not found for -l AFOAuth2Manager.

I followed some settings in StackOverflow and this still cannot be solved.

Build Active Architecture Only: NO